# rename_table: Relation "TABLE_pkey" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, migration

A really simple migration in Rails 4.1 fails and I don't see why. The error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "channel_entries_pkey" does not exist:
ALTER INDEX "channel_entries_pkey" RENAME TO "channels_projects_pkey"
```

Here's the migration:

```
class ConvertChannelEntriesToChannelsProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    remove_column :channel_entries, :position
    rename_table :channel_entries, :channels_projects
  end

  def down
    rename_table :channels_projects, :channel_entries
    add_column :channel_entries, :position, :integer
  end

end
```

A little background: The join between channels and projects has been a HM-THRU named channel_entries to accommodate an additional `position`. Since the position has been dropped, I'm switching to a simple HABTM and by convention, the join table should now be named channels_projects.

As I recall, `_pkey` indexes are automatically created for `foreign_key`s, but no foreign keys have ever existed on channel_entries. Why does `rename_table` want to rename this non-existant index?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, an old migration didn't fully work and left a constraint unrenamed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my solution for similar problem.
Below is the error while running migrations

```
01 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "fundraise_stories_pkey" does not exist
01 : ALTER INDEX "fundraise_stories_pkey" RENAME TO "fundraisers_pkey"
```

Connected to database via pgadmin and selected constraints for the table fundraise_stories. It was showing constraint name as "fundrise_stories_pkey". 
So it was some old mistake because constraint name doesnt match with table name.

Solution:

1. Find existing index name under constraints section for the table. In my case it was 'fundrise_stories_pkey'
2. Rename the index before renaming table
3. Finally, Rename the table.

Below is modified migration to rename index before renaming table.

```
def self.up
    execute "ALTER INDEX fundrise_stories_pkey RENAME TO fundraise_stories_pkey;"
    rename_table :fundraise_stories, :fundraisers
end
```

Log

```
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.428294 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
== 20200127102616 RenameFundraiseStoryTableToFundraisers: migrating ===========
-- execute("ALTER INDEX fundrise_stories_pkey RENAME TO fundraise_stories_pkey;")
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.434366 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (5.5ms)  ALTER INDEX fundrise_stories_pkey RENAME TO fundraise_stories_pkey;
   -> 0.0061s
-- rename_table(:fundraise_stories, :fundraisers)
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.435722 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ALTER TABLE "fundraise_stories" RENAME TO "fundraisers"
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.438769 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "public"."fundraise_stories_id_seq" RENAME TO "fundraisers_id_seq"
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.439334 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  ALTER INDEX "fundraise_stories_pkey" RENAME TO "fundraisers_pkey"
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.445452 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  ALTER INDEX "index_fundraise_stories_on_bank_account_id" RENAME TO "index_fundraisers_on_bank_account_id"
D, [2020-02-02T17:16:27.446153 #7363] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  ALTER INDEX "index_fundraise_stories_on_creator_id_and_creator_type" RENAME TO "index_fundraisers_on_creator_id_and_creator_type" 
   -> 0.0131s
== 20200127102616 RenameFundraiseStoryTableToFundraisers: migrated (0.0193s) ==
```